# Destination array is not long enough

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm trying to make a serial communication from Arduino to C# in Visual Studio. Here is my code. I use timer to request and receive the data.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isConnected = true;
        port.Write("A");

        int bytes = port.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
        port.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
        {
            int potensio = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
            string potString = Convert.ToString(potensio);
            label1.Text = potString;
        }
    }
```

Error in this line 
   `int potensio = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);`

```
    System.ArgumentException
      HResult = 0x80070057
      Message=Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection.Check array index and length.
      Source= mscorlib
      StackTrace:
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
       at System.BitConverter.ToInt32(Byte[] value, Int32 startIndex)
       at SerialTest.Form1.timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\ThinkPad\source\repos\SerialTest\SerialTest\Form1.cs:line 73
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at SerialTest.Program.Main() in C:\Users\ThinkPad\source\repos\SerialTest\SerialTest\Program.cs:line 19
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `int potensio = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);` looks very suspicious: you are ignoring the actual array size (which could be less then 4 bytes) and you ignore the index as well.

Comment: `BitConverter.ToInt32` needs 4 bytes to work from; is it possible that `bytes` is less than 4? if so... a: what do you expect it to do, and b: ... why are you doing the same work `bytes`-times (`for int i = 0 ; i < bytes ; i++)`), when `buffer` is *all* the bytes? In particular: note that in any IO scenario, just because you expect `n` bytes *eventually*, doesn't mean all `n` arrive *at the same time*; say you're expecting 42 bytes; you might receive them as 1, 10, 1, 37 (where 7 of the last 37 are actually related to the *next* message); your code needs to handle that

Comment: I'm trying to display potentiometer value in visual studio from Arduino..

Comment: Unfortunately there is probably no guarantee that you'll get 4 bytes every time you read "ports", they are probably arriving in chunks or even byte by byte, which means you will have to rewrite all your communication code to take this into account, and only run the conversion once you have 4 bytes. Additionally, the buffer might contain more than 4 bytes which means you're also getting bytes from the next value, which will have to be kept for the next value decoding.

Comment: @MarcGravell when I start the program and connect the port, everything works fine and it shows value, but when I wait for some time (very random) it shows the Exception and I see the bytes it's less than 4 bytes as expected.

Comment: @YusufPraditya yes, that happens; see my comment above, starting from "In particular:"

Comment: @MarcGravell When I'm not using for loop it shows exception error (from your question number 2)

Comment: Is there another method better than using Timer to request and receive data?

Comment: @YusufPraditya the problem isn't the timer; the problem is that you're not currently handling the fact that the data doesn't arrive in nice neat chunks of 4 bytes, and you really need to

Comment: @MarcGravell Using if statement for the loop?

Comment: @YusufPraditya I've tried to explain in an answer; hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k; let's try and fix this; the problem here is that data doesn't always arrive in nice neat chunks of what you want. In your case, you want to process 4 bytes at a time, so: let's try that:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
int bytesBuffered = 0;
bool inProgress = false;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!inProgress) {
        // presumably this means "send me the current data?"
        inProgress = true;
        port.Write("A");            
    }

    // read whatever we still need to make 4, if available
    int bytes = Math.Min(port.BytesToRead, 4 - bytesBuffered);
    if (bytes <= 0) return; // nothing to do right now

    // read the next few bytes, noting the offset
    bytes = port.Read(buffer, bytesBuffered, bytes);
    // TODO: check if bytes is <= 0 - if so, the port may have disconnected
    bytesBuffered += bytes;

    // check whether we have enough to update the UI
    if (bytesBuffered == 4)
    {
        // we now have 4 bytes; update the UI, and reset
        int potensio = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
        string potString = Convert.ToString(potensio);
        label1.Text = potString;

        // and issue a new A next time
        bytesBuffered = 0;
        inProgress = false;
    }
}
```

Note: if you get odd results, it is possible that you haven't accounted for "endianness" - a 4-byte integer can be encoded as "big endian" or "little endian", and your CPU can be "big endian" or "little endian" - the two need to match. If the results look insanely big (or insanely negative), try adding `Array.Reverse(buffer)` before the `ToInt32` call, preferably after a `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` check; i.e.

```
// we now have 4 bytes; update the UI, and reset
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(buffer); // fix endianness
int potensio = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
```

and if that gives the wrong result: reverse it!

```
// we now have 4 bytes; update the UI, and reset
if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(buffer); // fix endianness
int potensio = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
```

Comment: @MongZhu Oh I didn't know that before, thank you for letting me know that

Comment: @YusufPraditya no problem, and welcome to StackOverflow :)